# Why does Typescript throw an error when typing Redux-saga call parameter - TS2339

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

running into a TS2339 typing error with TS, stating that I can't find the parameter being defined in the interface type. Below are the two files that I have in question:

#### api-service-saga.ts

- Error on line `const res = yield call(fetchAllBooks, action.param);`
- It's complaining that param property (type `IBookAction` from `../actions`) does not exist on `IBookAction` and also on `ILoadSearchableBooks`

```
import { takeEvery, call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { Action, IBookAction } from '../actions';
import { fetchAllBooks } from '../service/books-service';
import { Book } from '../classes';

export default function* watcherSaga() {
    yield takeEvery(Action.FETCH_SEARCHABLE_BOOKS, searchableBooksSaga);
}

function* searchableBooksSaga(action: IBookAction) {
    try {
        const res = yield call(fetchAllBooks, action.param);
        const searchableBooks = res.data.reduce((books: Array<Book>, b: any) => {
            books.push(new Book(b));
            return books;
        }, [])
        yield put({ type: Action.LOAD_SEARCHABLE_BOOKS, searchableBooks });
    } catch (e) {
        yield put({ type: Action.FETCH_ERROR, error: e});
    }

}
```

And below is the file where I had defined the interfaces:

#### ../actions/index.ts

```
import { Action } from './action-constants';
import { Book } from '../classes';

export interface IAction {
    type: Action
}

// TODO: refactor into other action files if it gets too large.

// Nav Actions

export interface INavigateAction extends IAction {
    payload: string
}

export function navigateAction(newState: any): INavigateAction {
    console.log('Navigating to::', newState);
    return { type: Action.NAVIGATE_TO, payload: newState }
}

// Book Actions

export interface IFetchSearchableBookAction extends IAction {
    param: any // TODO: properly type the parameters.
}
export function fetchSerachableBooks(param: any): IBookAction {
    console.log('Fetching Searchable Books:', param);
    return { type: Action.FETCH_SEARCHABLE_BOOKS, param }
}

export interface ILoadSearchableBooks extends IAction {
    searchableBooks: Array<Book>
}

export { Action } from './action-constants';
export type IBookAction = IFetchSearchableBookAction | ILoadSearchableBooks;
```

As see in the last line, I am exporting `IBookAction` types, one of which is the `IFetchSearchableBookAction` which has the `param` property.

Full error that I am getting:

```
TS2339: Property 'param' does not exist on type 'IBookAction'.
Property 'param' does not exist on type 'IFetchSearchableBookAction'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `IBookAction` can be either `IFetchSearchableBookAction` or `ILoadSearchableBooks`, and `ILoadSearchableBooks` does not have `param` prop. Meaning, it can only be 50% sure that `action` has `param` prop, but not 100%.

What if `action` is `ILoadSearchableBooks` and not `IFetchSearchableBookAction`, then `param` will probably be `undefined`.

Workaround is to type guard to let Typescript know that this `action` is indeed `IFetchSearchableBookAction` and not `ILoadSearchableBooks`.

For example:

```js
function searchableBooksSaga(action: ILoadSearchableBooks | IFetchSearchableBookAction) {
  if ('param' in action) {
    const param = action.param;
  } else {
    const books = action.searchableBooks;
  }
}
```

See more info about how to type guard in Typescript [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html)